# Select multiple rows from Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to select multiple rows from my table where the `user_to` column equals(for e.g) `$me`.

It's a following table. So I wanna show the user everyone that is following them but instead the only thing I get is the latest person to follow them. I tried using `IN()` but that hasn't helped me. Can someone help ?

```
$user_data_query = $con->prepare('SELECT follow_id, user_from FROM following ');
//$user_data_query->bind_param("s", $username);
$user_data_query->execute();
$user_data_query->bind_result($follow_id, $user_from); 
$user_data_query_result = $user_data_query->get_result();

while ($row = $user_data_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $user_from = $row['user_from'];
}  

<div class="friends_column list_column" id="main_section">

    <p id="friends"><?php echo "Followers: " . $user_from ?></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've selected all of the rows, but you're overwriting the variable in each iteration of the loop:

```
$user_from = $row['user_from'];
```

Instead, output the values in the loop:

```
<div class="friends_column list_column" id="main_section">
<?php
while ($row = $user_data_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <p id="friends"><?php echo "Followers: " . $row['user_from'] ?></p>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```